Spectral measures and spectral families
I've been reading Werner Amrein's book "Hilbert Space methods in quantum mechanics", but I get stuck at the beginning of Section 4.2
When he defines a spectral family of operators $\{E_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$, its says that the condition $E_{\lambda}E_{\mu}=E_{min\{\lambda,\mu\}}$ can also be written as $E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda}$ being a positive operator if $\lambda\leq\mu$. However, I don't know how to prove that both conditions are equivalent.
If I start supposing that $E_{\lambda}E_{\mu}=E_{min\{\lambda,\mu\}}$ I don't see how to prove that $\langle f,(E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda})(f)\rangle\geq0$ for all $f\in\mathcal{D}(E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda})$ (the domain of $E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda}$). I write $\langle f,(E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda})(f)\rangle=\langle f,E_{\mu}(f)\rangle+\langle f,E_{\lambda}(f)\rangle$ but from here I don't know what to do.
My next question is about the definition of the spectral measure. Once we have a spectral family, given $(a,b]$ with $a<b$, we define $E((a,b]):=E_{b}-E_a$. This associates a positive operator $E((a,b])$ to each half-open interval $(a,b]$. Then, Amrein says that, as for numerical measures, we can extend the family of operators defined as $E((a,b]):=E_{b}-E_a$ to all the elements of the Borel $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and associate a projection $E(\mathcal{V})$ with each Borel set $\mathcal{V}$. My question is; how do you do that?
In the case of Stieltjes measures, given a function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is
a) monotone non-decreasing,
b) right continuous,
c) $F(-\infty)=0$, and $F(+\infty)=\rho<\infty$,
we define $m^{F}(a,b]):=F(b)-F(a)$. Then, if $\mathcal{V}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we define
$$m^{F}(\mathcal{V}):=\text{inf}(\sum_{k}m^{F}(J_k))$$
where $\{J_k\}$ is a sequence of half-open intervals covering $\mathcal{V}$. However, for me it is not obvious that we can define the spectral measure in a similar way. To do that, we would need the notion of infimum, which implies some notion of partial order in the set of projection operators. I understand that this could be done saying that, for two projections $E_\mu, E_\nu$, $E_\nu\leq E_\mu$ if $\langle f,(E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda})(f)\rangle\geq0$ for all $f\in\mathcal{D}(E_{\mu}-E_{\lambda})$. I have proved that this defines, under other assumtions and technicalities, a partial order. However, I'm not sure if this is the right way to proceed.
I think that, being more formal, what Amrein tries to explain is the following theorem:
Theorem:a) Let $E$ be a spectral measure defined over the Borel $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then, there exist a unique spectral family $\{E_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ such that $E((a,b])=E_b-E_a$ for al half-open interval $(a,b]$.
b) Let $\{E_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a spectral family. Then, there exist a unique spectral measure $E$ defined over the Borel $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and such that $E((a,b])=E_b-E_a$ for al half-open interval $(a,b]$.
Is there a reference where I could find such type of result and its proof?
I have checked other books like Reed and Simon, and Joachim Weidman, but none of them expose the subject in this way, and none of them have a theorem similar to what I have written.
